# uClibc Static Compilation Quеstion

Tags: gcc, static, linker, ld, uclibc

I am trying to cross compile for an ARM-based single board computer.  I am using a uClibc toolchain designed for the board. I am extremely space constrained as far as ROM size goes, so I am trying to compile with binary size in mind. (Memory footprint is not an issue)

I am currently using a command that looks like this to compile:

```
arm-uclibc-3.4.6/bin/arm-linux-gcc -Wall -mcpu=arm9 mongoose.c main.c -o mongoose -ldl -    pthread -W -std=c99 -pedantic -Wl,--rpath,/slib -Wl,-dynamic-linker,/slib/ld-uClibc.so.0 -static -g -Os
```

Right now, I need to static link a few libraries that are not stored on the embedded target.  However, there is one shared library on the board that the program can dynamically link to, ld-uClibc.so.0.

What I am trying to figure out is how to dynamically link ld-uClibc.so.0 and statically link the rest of the libraries I need.